# Unable to pass command line to new exe created by CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I am now trying to call an .exe from my application written in C++
The exe that I am trying to call is a Kermit program (k95.exe) - a file transfer app.

Without using C++, I am able type in command at the Kermit program and it works.

[image: Able to key in "Take connect.txt" command]
However, now I am trying use `CreateProcess()` to call this 'Kermit' program in my application.

At this stage, I am able to call up 'Kermit' program successfully.
The Kermit application able to launch up successfully.

Now, we want to key in the "Take connect.txt" into the console through my C++ application and we got no idea how to proceed.

I know that we able to pass in command `CreateProcess()`, some sort like passing function parameters but I do not intend to close this Kermit program immediately.
In between, I may still want to use it for other operation such as Download or Upload file.

We can't do all above because `CreateProcess()` does not return a window handle.

---

### Notes

1. "Take" used above is one of the command for k95.exe
2. Here's my CreateProcess function located:

   ```
           bool LaunchKermitExe( const char path, char cmdLine)
           {
            STARTUPINFO         si;
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess, saThread;
            PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcess;
            bool bSuccess;
            DWORD lasterr;


            // setup STARTUPINFO struct
            ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
            si.cb = sizeof(si);

            // make new process handle inheritable
            saProcess.nLength = sizeof(saProcess);
            saProcess.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
            saProcess.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

            // make the new thread handle not inheritable
            saThread.nLength = sizeof(saThread);
            saThread.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
            saThread.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

            bSuccess = CreateProcess(path, cmdLine, NULL, NULL,TRUE,
                    0, NULL, NULL, &si, &piProcess);

            lasterr = GetLastError();

            // now close handles to detach the process
             CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
             CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);

            return bSuccess;
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to do is write to the stdin of that process. I am not familiar with the windows CreateProcess api, so you're gonna have to do some looking yourself.  [This example on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx) shows several examples with reading a file and stuff into stdin of the called process. There is no easy way to do this kind of thing, so prepare to learn lots about pipes!

Answer (score 0):

The Kermit app clearly has its own command processor for user input. You will have to redirect its STDIN when creating the process so you can write your own data to it as needed.  There is a section of MSDN that describes this in detail:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)